# hibernate inner join

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

i need inner join with

**"select rc.* from"**

```
"from RateCode rc inner join rc.rateCodeParams rcCod where rc.rateCodeId = rcCod.id and rc.travelFrom <= '2011-05-09' and rc.travelTo >= '2011-05-13' and rc.active = 1" +
        " and rcCod.paramVal like '%" + roomId + "%'"
```

rateCodeParam.hbm

```
<class catalog="hermes" name="RateCodeParam" table="ratecodeparam">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <column name="id"/>
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="paramVal" type="string">
      <column length="45" name="paramVal"/>
    </property>
 <many-to-one class="RateCode" insert="false" name="rateCode" update="false">
      <column name="p_id"/>
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

rateCode.hbm

```
<class catalog="hermes" name="RateCode" table="ratecodes">
    <id name="rateCodeId" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <column name="id"/>
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
<set cascade="all, delete-orphan" name="rateCodeParams" order-by="param">
      <key>
        <column name="p_id"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="RateCodeParam"/>
</set>
</class>
```

Comment: select rc from RateCode rc inner join rc.rateCodeParams rcCod where rc.rateCodeId = rcCod.id and rc.travelFrom <= '2011-05-09' and rc.travelTo >= '2011-05-13' and rc.active = 1" +
        " and rcCod.paramVal like '%" + roomId + "%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inner join` to a collection should be done like:

```
from RateCode rc inner join rc.rateCodeParams rcCod where rc.rateCodeId = rcCod.id and rc.travelFrom <= '2011-05-09' and rc.travelTo >= '2011-05-13' and rc.active = 1" +
            " and rcCod.paramVal like '%" + roomId + "%'"
```

More on this topic at the manual

[1]http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: hi thanks for ur help one thing more is how would i get "select rc.* from..." from above i got Object[2] - > RateCode(0) , RateCodeParam(1)

Comment: What do you want to do, sorry but I think I don't get the question. If you do select rc from RateCode where... what returns?